# Can I prevent two divs with 50% width from dropping at odd widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a containing `div` that is 100% and two divs that are 50% width:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="half">Box 1</div>
     <div class="half">Box 2</div>
</div>

.container {
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
}
.half {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
}
```

Obviously if the screen width is an even number like `960px` then this works find but `961px` is causing the right box to drop. I know why this happens: 961 doesn't deven evenly by 2 resulting in the box on the left to round up. Is there a technique I can use to prevent this without JS/jQuery?

Comment: try putting that code into jsfiddle. It works fine. You have something else going on

Comment: I tried. For some reason the place where I am right now is preventing jsfiddle form loading, not sure why.

Comment: Well the browser has no problem with odd pixels and should be able to figure out 50% regardless. There is very likely some other style affecting the layout

Comment: Everything is pretty basic and running the Eric Meyer's reset. My `half` divs have `display: table` and `position: relative` applied as well but that doesn't seem to have any affect when I turn that off and on.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue using the code provided. Perhaps if there was a codepen or jsfiddle illustrating the issue we could better troubleshoot it

Comment: I know, jsfiddle and codepen  are both acting up at my current location. I'll update this question with one of them when I get to a better connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your half divs in one div and use display: table;

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class"half"></div>
  <div class"half"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{ display: table; }
.half{ display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it´s working, but you could try using dynamic margins with someting like `margin: 0px auto`. And than doing something like 49% width for the halfs

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not you have some sort of padding or margin applied to the elements. You can avoid padding issues by applying box-sizing to both elements and zeroing out the margins:

```
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
```

note: this is not compatible with ie8 and below

Comment: didn't appear to have any affect

Comment: What browser are you using?